# updating jmeter Dataset config to update tokens in it with another thread

Tags: multithreading, api, csv, jmeter

[Error Image Jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Deb6Z.png)
[Error Image JTL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPOrq.png)

My API calls take token which is valid for 4 min. In CSV data set config file, we have records with tokens placed in each row for each user. I am running this test for 20 min. I am running JMeter in CLI mode and running another thread to update it every 2 min. Thread uses a custom library to create tokens.

Now the issue is: just in some cases, Jmeter reads the file while it is being updated by a separate thread and this causes errors.

**How I know this is caused by thread :**

1. This error appears after the thread updates the file. before it, everything works fine.
2. My CSV has parameters 
   server,portNumber,userId,username,password,teamspaceID,Token

and in JMeter script using URL like "Http://${server}:${portNumber}"
but in .jtl file, few of the records have "Http:// some part of token string:8082"

Is there any other efficient way to tackle this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team lead has solved this by using database. Now we are writing header parameters in database instead of csv file from thread, and in jmeter using pre-processor to get values from database to update in header properties.

In addition we are writing three sets of data. Thread is updating the oldest data and jmeter is using latest data by using order by in pre-processor query.

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), JMeter's CSV Data Set Config doesn't expect that the file can change during the runtime, it's hard to come up with the exact solution without seeing your test plan, however you can consider the following alternatives:

1. Generating token right before the request using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), by default the time taken by the PreProcessors is not included into Sampler's elapsed time so you will get only HTTP request execution time in the results file
2. Putting logic which is not thread safe under [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller)
3. Using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/) instead of interim CSV file for keeping/passing the tokens